# "How is it going for you " vs "How has it been going for you"

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

If I want to ask someone if something is working out for them. What should I say?

> 1. How is that working for you so far?
> 2. How has that been working for you so far?

Answer (score 1):

I’d use the second version.

“So far” implies that we are referring to the period from when they started with it up until the present, which is in the past, so I’d use the past tense statement.

If I wanted to refer to the fact that they are still using it, and ask for a more “current state” update, I’d simply say:

> How is that working for you?

With that said, I do believe the first version would be found to be acceptable, especially in speech.